# How do I calculate this standard normal probability with absolute value?

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

So I have two problems that I can't think of how to do for the life of me as they both deal with the absolute Z score.
1.) $P(|Z| \le 0.38)$ and The value of x for which $P(|Z| \le x) = 0.31 $
Now from both I know that the score is going to be negative since it's pointing to the left and is less than 0.5. AM I on the right track so far?

Comment: $$
P(|Z| \le x) =\Phi (-x\leq Z \leq x)=\Phi (x)-\Phi(-x)=\Phi (x)-(1-\Phi (x))=2\Phi (x)-1
$$

Comment: $P(|Z| \le 0.38)$ just means $P(-0.38 \le Z\le 0.38)$

Comment: Alright so what about the other question?

Comment: For the other question, use similar logic with the inverse normal function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answers from R statistical software [where `pnorm` is $\Phi,$ standard normal CDF, and `qnorm` is $\Phi^{-1}$, standard normal quantile function (inverse CDF)]. If you are using printed standard normal CDF
tables, then some rounding may be necessary, so your answers may not be *exactly*
the same as mine.

(1) $P(|Z| < 0.38) = P(-0.38 < Z < 0.38) = 2P(0 < Z < 0.38) = 0.2961.$

```
2*(pnorm(0.38)-.5)
## 0.2960546
diff(pnorm(c(-.38,.38)))
## 0.2960546
```

(2) $z$ such that $P(|Z|< x) = 0.31$ is the same as $z$ such that
$P(Z < -z) = (1-.31)/2 = 0.345.$ So $z \approx 0.40.$

```
qnorm(.345)
## -0.3988551
```

Because I don't know what style of normal tables you have, I can't tell
you exactly how to use yours. Under the standard normal curve below, there
are four areas bounded by vertical broken lines. From left to right
their areas are 0.345, 0.155, 0.155, and 0.345, respectively. You will
have to look in the body of the table for the relevant area, then read
0.4 (or -0.4) from the margin of the table.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the graphical representation I'm assuming there isn't a way to calculate this by hand? I don't know if my professor wants us to use our calculator to find the answer XD

Comment: For the present, I think it is worthwhile for you to figure out how to use a printed normal table. But some sort of numerical method is necessary to get normal probabilities. Many fairly inexpensive scientific calculators will do the job. Also R statistical software is reliable and free (from `r-project.org`) . It can be daunting if you try to learn everything about it, but learning just the probability functions is very simple. // You should ask you professor what the expectations are for computations in your course.